# how to get data from relational tables (many to many)

Tags: mysql, sql

[image]

I have these three main tables **Microdisenos**, **competencias** and **resultados**.

My problem is this: I want to know what are the **resultados** that belong to the **competencias** of a **microdisenos**.

I know how to do it when relationships are one to many, but in this case it is many to many and I do not know how to handle those intermediate tables.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Can you clarify, what have you tried and what was wrong joining tables ?

Comment: The difference between one to many and many to many? You just need two joins instead of one. Chain the tables together. There should be foreign key relationships guiding you about which joins to make.

Answer (score 1):

The only way is to join throught all the columns:

```
SELECT * (or whatever you need)
FROM resultados r
 INNER JOIN competencia_resultado cr
  ON r.id = cr.resultado_id
 INNER JOIN cometencias c
  ON c.id = cr.cometencia_id
 INNER JOIN competencia_microdisendo cm
  ON c.id = cm.competencia_id
 INNER JOIN microdisendos m
  ON m.id = cm.microdisendo_id
```

And if you want to select just the once that belong to one specific microdesendo add the WHERE clause with m.id

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE DATABASE testDB;

USE testDB;


CREATE TABLE microdisenos (
  id INTEGER UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  description VARCHAR(255),
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE competencias (
  id INTEGER UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  modulo VARCHAR(128),
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE competencia_microdiseno (
  id INTEGER UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  microdiseno_id INTEGER UNSIGNED,
  competencia_id INTEGER UNSIGNED,
  PRIMARY KEY (id),
  FOREIGN KEY (microdiseno_id) REFERENCES microdisenos (id),
  FOREIGN KEY (competencia_id) REFERENCES competencias (id)
);

CREATE TABLE resultados (
  id INTEGER UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  description VARCHAR(256),
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE competencia_resultado(
  id INTEGER UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  resultado_id INTEGER UNSIGNED,
  competencia_id INTEGER UNSIGNED,
  PRIMARY KEY (id),
  FOREIGN KEY (resultado_id) REFERENCES resultados (id),
  FOREIGN KEY (competencia_id) REFERENCES competencias (id)
);

INSERT INTO competencias VALUES (0, 'Compentencia AA');
INSERT INTO competencias VALUES (0, 'Compentencia BB');
INSERT INTO competencias VALUES (0, 'Compentencia CC');
INSERT INTO competencias VALUES (0, 'Compentencia DD');
INSERT INTO competencias VALUES (0, 'Compentencia EE');

INSERT INTO microdisenos VALUES (0, 'Microdisenos 101');
INSERT INTO microdisenos VALUES (0, 'Microdisenos 202');
INSERT INTO microdisenos VALUES (0, 'Microdisenos 303');
INSERT INTO microdisenos VALUES (0, 'Microdisenos 404');
INSERT INTO microdisenos VALUES (0, 'Microdisenos 505');

INSERT INTO resultados VALUES (0, 'Resultados 11');
INSERT INTO resultados VALUES (0, 'Resultados 22');
INSERT INTO resultados VALUES (0, 'Resultados 33');
INSERT INTO resultados VALUES (0, 'Resultados 44');
INSERT INTO resultados VALUES (0, 'Resultados 55');

INSERT INTO competencia_microdiseno VALUES(0, 1, 1);
INSERT INTO competencia_microdiseno VALUES(0, 1, 2);
INSERT INTO competencia_microdiseno VALUES(0, 1, 3);
INSERT INTO competencia_microdiseno VALUES(0, 2, 4);
INSERT INTO competencia_microdiseno VALUES(0, 2, 5);
INSERT INTO competencia_microdiseno VALUES(0, 3, 1);
INSERT INTO competencia_microdiseno VALUES(0, 3, 2);
INSERT INTO competencia_microdiseno VALUES(0, 4, 3);
INSERT INTO competencia_microdiseno VALUES(0, 4, 4);
INSERT INTO competencia_microdiseno VALUES(0, 4, 5);
INSERT INTO competencia_microdiseno VALUES(0, 5, 1);
INSERT INTO competencia_microdiseno VALUES(0, 5, 2);
INSERT INTO competencia_microdiseno VALUES(0, 5, 3);


INSERT INTO competencia_resultado VALUES(0, 1, 1);
INSERT INTO competencia_resultado VALUES(0, 2, 2);
INSERT INTO competencia_resultado VALUES(0, 3, 3);
INSERT INTO competencia_resultado VALUES(0, 4, 4);
INSERT INTO competencia_resultado VALUES(0, 5, 5);
INSERT INTO competencia_resultado VALUES(0, 1, 1);
INSERT INTO competencia_resultado VALUES(0, 2, 2);
INSERT INTO competencia_resultado VALUES(0, 3, 3);
INSERT INTO competencia_resultado VALUES(0, 4, 4);
INSERT INTO competencia_resultado VALUES(0, 5, 5);
INSERT INTO competencia_resultado VALUES(0, 1, 1);
INSERT INTO competencia_resultado VALUES(0, 2, 2);
INSERT INTO competencia_resultado VALUES(0, 3, 3);


-- Give me all (unique) Resultados for Compentencias for given Microdisenos  
SELECT DISTINCT r.*
  FROM resultados r, competencia_resultado cr, competencias c, competencia_microdiseno cm, microdisenos m
 WHERE r.id = cr.resultado_id
  AND  c.id = cr.competencia_id
  AND  c.id = cm.competencia_id
  AND  m.id = cm.microdiseno_id
  AND  m.description = "Microdisenos 303";
```

The result would be:

```
# id, description
----  ---------------
   1, Resultados 11
   2, Resultados 22
```

**Option 2:**
Subquery

```
SELECT DISTINCT r.*
 FROM resultados r
WHERE r.id IN ( SELECT DISTINCT cr.id
                  FROM competencia_resultado cr
                 WHERE cr.competencia_id IN ( 
                            SELECT DISTINCT c.id
                              FROM competencias c
                             WHERE c.id IN (
                                    SELECT DISTINCT cm.competencia_id 
                                      FROM competencia_microdiseno cm, microdisenos m 
                                     WHERE m.id = cm.microdiseno_id
                                       AND  m.description = "Microdisenos 303" )
                              )
                );
```